# How to implement Navigation Drawer inside a Fragment

Tags: android, navigation, android-viewpager, fragment, navigation-drawer

I have implemented `TabLayout` with `ViewPager` on the Activity. On selecting different tabs the `Viewpager` replace the page with a Fragment. But, Now my use case is to implement a Navigation Drawer inside a `Fragment.xml` but i am unable to do it.

When I am writing the `DrawerLayout` as the root layout in the `Fragment.xml` and child layout are `AppBarLayout` and `FrameLayout`.

Structure:

```
<DrawerLayout>
    <AppBarLayout><ToolBarLayout/><AppBarLayout>
    <FrameLayout/>
    <Navigation Menu/>
</DrawerLayout>
```

All the toolbar from different tabs are going above screen and it's height is not in actionBarSize height and `ToolBar` height is shrinked and the `TabLayout` is shrinked.

Comment: Could you show us your layouts?

Answer (score 1):

understanding that the drawer layout will be placed inside the fragment then simply gain access to that fragment through an xml layout and add the drawer insider the layout.

the structure i would follow would be the following (in pseudocode):

```
<relativelayout>
name:outside-container-for-drawerlyout
height: ... and width: ...
 <relativelayout>
  name:actual-continer-for-drawerlayout
  height: ... and width: ...
  <!-- place drawer layout code here -->
  <drawerayout>
  height: ... and width: ...
   <!-- nest navigation view code here -->
   <navview>
    height: ... and width: ...
   </navview>
  </drawerlayout>
 </relativelayout>
</relativelayout>
```

peek at the documentation, [android documentation reference for navigation drawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer) it's similar.
this will ensure that you place your drawer and it's layouts below the tabbed layout you're already seeing.

then, on your fragment inside the java:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(...) {
...
rootView = inflater.inflate(R..., container, false);
handleAccountNavigator();
return rootView;
}
private void handleAccountNavigator(){
this.mDrawerLayout = this.rootView.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
this.mNavigationView = this.rootView.findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
new Handler().post(new Runnable()... to handle drawer actions.
}
```

[image]

Comment: In the Fragment.xml ToolBar is the First Child and my Tablayout is at the bottom which of ActionBarSize and the remaining portion is DrawerLayout of 100dp width and height is Match Parent and layout_above TabLayout. So after 100dp width my frameLayout reside.